# Convert String to Date Issue (Date Parsing) in JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a String like **"05/30/2012"** to a Date as same like **"05/30/2012"** and I'm using these codes.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Date d1=formatter.parse("05/30/2012");

System.out.println(d1);
```

But these codes compile result is : 
**"Wed May 30 00:00:00 EEST 2012"** 
I need **"05/30/2012"**.

**Note: I'm trying to convert String to Date. I have a Date column in Database. I don't want to change it's format. I just want 05/30/2012 in my database but as a Date class not a String. parse() method is changing my date to another format I want to keep it's format**

I've solved it.

```
java.sql.Date dd = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse("05/30/2012").getTime());
System.out.println(dd);
```

and now its result is : **05/30/2012**

Comment: You already have a `Date` in the right format. The println output is just a bit ugly.

Comment: I have a String like "05/30/2012" iam trying to change it's type to Date but it's a String.And when i use parse() method it's changing my Date's format like "Wed May 30 00:00:00 EEST 2012" but i want to keep it as "05/30/2012"

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `format()` method then

By the way what is the point of conversion here if you already have string formatted?

if you just say `System.out.println(dateinstance);` then it will invoke `toString()` method of Date  class which has fixed format,

So if you just want the conversion from String to Date then you can do it using `parse()` method,

If you want formatted conversion from Date to String then you need to use `format()` method

Comment: That's actually a good question :) .. i'm guessing he wants to format any date to this format and the code above is just a simple example.

Comment: Iam just trying to convert same string to same Date class.Thats all.I dont want to change it's format.

Comment: Updated the answer, Please check

Comment: i used parse but it changed my String to "Wed May 30 00:00:00 EEST 2012" but i want "05/30/2012"

Comment: then you need to use `String formattedDate = df.format(dateInstance);  as I mentioned earlier`

Answer (score 2):

try: `System.out.println(formatter.format(d1));`

Comment: it does not work and i need it in 'Date' class.Because i have a Date column in my database.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? formatter.format(d1) will format the date obj into the format you specified. The result will be 05/30/2012.

Comment: but in String right ? I want it in Date class Please read question again i edited it.

Comment: hm.. i'm not sure about this .. your doing an insert into your db? There could be a sql function like format(date, "MM/dd/yyyy") which will do what you want.

Comment: Iam inserting sometimes.But sometimes i need to select it and use as Date class in my methods.So i need it in java :/

Comment: When you do a select you get a String "05/30/2012" right? So you can use for this case the formatter to convert it into an Date object. When you want to Update/Insert you can use the sql-function.

Comment: Iam just doing it.But when i try to parse it to a Date like at top im getting a wrong format like at top :/

Answer (score 1):

Just as you need to specify the format when parsing the date, you also need to specify the format when printing it, otherwise you get the default format that you are seeing.

Try:

System.out.println(formatter.format(d1))

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d1=formatter.parse("05/30/2012");
String out = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(out);
```

The `parse` method will build a `Date` from a String with the given pattern, but your `System.out.println(d1);`
 will just call a `Date.toString()`.

To print the `Date` with a custom format, you should use `SimpleDateFormatter.format` that will return the String as you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(d1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The date is parsed, and in the `System.out.println()` call, the default implementation of `Date.toString()` is used. *Note: the date doesn't know the format used for parsing*

To "fix" it, i.e. do what you want, write

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(d1));
```

instead.